# Plugin for TinyMCE - how to remove added code?

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce

all!

I'm writing a little Plugin for TinyMCE 4.
What the plugin does is now not important. I can add a code to the page.

My problem is, that I need the possibility to **remove** the added code, too...
And I can't...

Here my code:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('subpages', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('subpages', {
        image: url + '/subpages.png',
        title: 'Liste der Unterseiten',
        onclick: function() {
            editor.insertContent('<div style="width: 100%">BLAH</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

What should I do to allow the user to remove the added "DIV" from the page?
With other plugin I can just click on the element and remove it, but for my element it does not work...

Thanks a lot
Luca Bertoncello

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a `data-` attribute to the div and then look for that using JavaScript?  You could then remove that DOM element from the content via JavaScript and the remaining content would be untouched.

If multiple instances of your code can appear in the editor the `data-` attribute would allow you to uniquely define each one

```
<div data-myplugin-id="1">....</div>
.
.
.
<div data-myplugin-id="2">....</div>
```

...so the unique values in `data-myplugin-id` would allow you to target each one specifically.

Comment: Hi Michael. You didn't unterstood my problem... I know how can I remove an element from DOM. What I need is to know how can I create this element, so that I can click and remove it **from TinyMCE**!